# What is the fastest way of querying neo4j over REST?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, cypher

I am using NEO4J over REST in my project and its a sort of social network so a lot of queries have to be run for even very small stuff like incrementing views, likes, following, friends and other minute stuff. Right now I am using the '@Query' method by extending the GraphRepository for sending queries to the database.

for example

`@Query ("Match n Return n")
public List<Node> ReturnNodes();`

Is there a faster way to do all this smaller stuff ?

Thanks.

Comment: This will probably lead to biased answers I'm afraid. One of those answers could be: write your own HTTP client around Neo4j REST APIs ;P

Comment: Use indices (such Labels), fetch more data (i.e. followings, friends) and cache it. It looks to me that the problem is not strictly related to Neo4J here...

Comment: Thanks guys. I am building indexes on almost everything. Anyways I wanted to ask one specific thing though, Would using RestGraphDatabase queryEngine be a better idea or the one above ?

Comment: I meant RestCypherQueryEngine

Comment: I believe if your project is open source you can use the enterprise version of Neo4j.

Comment: already using the enterprise edition